# Incorrect return behaviour of android app

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-task

I have my android app with some strange bug: in some scenarios when it's finished "returning" behaviour is incorrect. To be more clear:

- I open any android application, Calculator for example.
- I press home button and start my application from launcher.
- In some scenarios when I close my app I don't return to home screen. Instead of that I see the previous opened app (Calculation in our case).

What can possibly cause this behaviour? My app with one activity starts with standard flags ("New task", "no history", "no recent").

Comment: How do you close your app, with back button?

Comment: just calling finish().